# maven-compiler-plugin Compilation Failure trying to build HDFS

Tags: java, maven, hadoop, hdfs, maven-compiler-plugin

I'm trying to build an HDFS distribution. However, I can't get past the 
    mvn clean install
I always got into

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.5.1:compile (default-compile) on project hadoop-hdfs: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
```

And followed by a lot of Compile Error.
such as

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.5.1:compile (default-compile) on project hadoop-hdfs: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /Users/janinkuwijitsuwan/Desktop/hadoop-common/hadoop-hdfs-project/hadoop-hdfs/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/hdfs/protocolPB/PBHelper.java:[2405,12] constructor FileEncryptionInfo in class org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileEncryptionInfo cannot be applied to given types;
[ERROR] required: org.apache.hadoop.crypto.CipherSuite,org.apache.hadoop.crypto.CryptoProtocolVersion,byte[],byte[],java.lang.String,java.lang.String
[ERROR] found: org.apache.hadoop.crypto.CipherSuite,byte[],byte[],java.lang.String
[ERROR] reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
[ERROR] /Users/janinkuwijitsuwan/Desktop/hadoop-common/hadoop-hdfs-project/hadoop-hdfs/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/hdfs/DFSClient.java:[1322,50] method createForDecryption in class org.apache.hadoop.crypto.key.KeyProviderCryptoExtension.EncryptedKeyVersion cannot be applied to given types;
[ERROR] required: java.lang.String,java.lang.String,byte[],byte[]
```

Here is my mvn --version

```
Apache Maven 3.3.3 (7994120775791599e205a5524ec3e0dfe41d4a06; 2015-04-22T20:57:37+09:00)
Maven home: /usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.3.3/libexec
Java version: 1.8.0_73, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_73.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.11.3", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

Here is a link to my hadoop-hdfs/pom.xml

https://www.dropbox.com/s/6bov72gk4lidg5b/pom.xml?dl=0

Comment: Isn't your IDE also complaining about errors in your code?

Comment: @aribeiro I'm using Terminal to compile it. When I use Eclipse it always say I don't have my protoc and it didn't return version number (even though I can do that in Terminal). So I decided to use Terminal to compile instead. BTW, it's just ordinary HDFS without any modification. I'm still figuring out how dependency works here.